# Формы глагола и время

Tags: глаголы

Есть ли какие то формы глаголов, у которых нельзя определить время? В тесте написал, что нет. А ответ не верный. Так и не понял, ничего толком не объяснил препод.

Answer (score 1):

У [инфинитивов](https://qa.studwork.org/russkiy-yazyk/34385-v-kakoy-forme-glagola-nelzya-opredelit-vremya-i-pochemu) нельзя определить)

Answer (score 1):

В помощь выпускникам,  которым **"ничего толком не объяснил препод"**.

Время нельзя определить **у инфинитива, но не только!**

1. **Глагол** – часть речи, обозначающая действие или состояние предмета. Значение действия выражается в вопросах: *что делать, что делал, что делает, что сделать, что сделал, что сделает.*
   Основными **грамматическими категориями глагола являются:**

(1) постоянные признаки: вид, переходность, возвратность, спряжение,

(2) непостоянные признаки: наклонение, **время**, лицо, число, а также род.

2. Начальная форма глагола называется **инфинитивом** или неопределенной формой глагола. Инфинитив обозначает действие **вне его отношения к производителю действия и к моменту речи** и отвечает на вопросы *что делать, что сделать*. Инфинитив имеет грамматические значения **вида и переходности, но не времени.**
3. **Время можно определить** только для глаголов в форме  **изъявительного наклонения**.

Наклонение выражает отношение действия к реальности.

(1) ИЗЪЯВИТЕЛЬНОЕ наклонение обозначает **реальное** действие, протекающее **во времени**, например: *я  **пишу** письмо,  **написал** письмо* или ***напишу** письмо*. Грамматическое значение  времени имеют только глаголы в изъявительном наклонении.

(2) ПОВЕЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ наклонение выражает побуждение к действию, но не само действие, например: ***напиши** письмо* или ***напишите** письмо*.

(3) УСЛОВНОЕ (сослагательное) наклонение обозначает действие, которое могло бы иметь место при каких-либо условиях или желательное действие: *я **написал бы** письмо*.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**

**Форма прошедшего времени** используется при образовании условного наклонения, но грамматическое значение времени она **не выражает.**